# Who approved the deployment in VSTS?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS to deploy to remote machines. Before deployment, VSTS asks for PreDeployment approval.
Is there any variable or any way to get the name of the approver?
I can get it from history but then it is too late.
I know how to get the name of the person who triggered the deployment

```
$(Release.Deployment.RequestedFor)
```

[Microsoft doesn't seem to mention anything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch)

Comment: You could use the REST API. What is your end-goal here? What do you want to do with the name of the approver once you have it?

Comment: I want to get the approver and pass him as an argument to a powershell script I am running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to get the pre-deployment approval during the deployment.

And the pre-defined variables `$(Release.Deployment.RequestedFor)` is not used for your situation since it’s the variable shows the display name who create the release (not the user who approve the release before deployment).

To get the pre-deployment approval, you can use the REST API [Get release:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

```
GET https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.2
```

For the release id, you can use the predefined variable `$( Release.ReleaseId)`. And you can get the per-deployment approval from the response as below:

```
    "preApprovalsSnapshot": {
        "approvals": [
            {
                "rank": 1,
                "isAutomated": false,
                "isNotificationOn": false,
                "approver": {
                    "displayName": "marina liu",
                    "url": "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/A2336cdc9-ffd7-41bb-a6cf-19002c9a9d5f/_apis/Identities/18cb43b4-0b0d-43ad-94dc-c8e2b56704c0",
                    "_links": {
                        "avatar": {
                            "href": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/msa.YjE2YzFlOWUtNWJkYy03NzU1LWJjNWEtNDU4M2Q5ZThlMjk0"
                        }
                    },
                    "id": "18cb43b4-0b0d-43ad-94dc-c8e2b56704c0",
                    "uniqueName": "****@****.com",
                    "imageUrl": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/_api/_common/identityImage?id=18cb43b4-0b0d-43ad-94dc-c8e2b56704c0",
                    "descriptor": "msa.YjE2YzFlOWUtNWJkYy03NzU1LWJjNWEtNDU4M2Q5ZThlMjk0"
                },
                "id": 0
            }
        ],
        "approvalOptions": {
            "requiredApproverCount": null,
            "releaseCreatorCanBeApprover": true,
            "autoTriggeredAndPreviousEnvironmentApprovedCanBeSkipped": false,
            "enforceIdentityRevalidation": false,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "executionOrder": "beforeGates"
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I knew about the REST API but I was hoping there would be an easier way. Microsoft enjoys making our life difficult.

Comment: There can be multiple approvers. It looks like you wanted them to be in variables... What is it that you wanted to do with them?