# Approval information on deployment job in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using a deployment job in my Azure Pipeline that uses an environment that require an approval before deploy. This works fine, but now I need the information about who approved the deployment (similar to [Who approved the deployment in VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641579/who-approved-the-deployment-in-vsts)).

How can I obtain this information in azure pipelines? I didn't find anything about this in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not able to do this at the moment. There is no documented API.

We already have a related community feature request here, you could vote up it and track the status:

> **Multi-Stage Pipeline variable for Environment approval**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/925034/multi-stage-pipeline-variable-for-environment-appr.html