# Azure DevOps Release.ApproverDisplayName variable not Found

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I use Azure DevOps predefined variables for many functions and reports I had earlier used a variable like
**Release.Approver**/**Release.ApproverDisplayName** which would contain details about who approved a stage for deployment but now when I search in the documentation it is no where to be found

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch

I tested using same variable, only to get a empty string in return please mention if there is any way I could get the approver details or Name in release stages of Azure DevOps thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this info can only be retrieved with the help of REST API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672992/274535